# Is there evidence you can increase penis length after puberty with hormones?

Tags: penis

I have seen things like [Kim & Song (2008)](https://www.jpurol.com/article/S1477-5131(08)00121-6/abstract) and [Laron, et al. (1983)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/6406387) but since I can't read all of it I need to ask here....

### References

Kim, K. S., & Song, G. G. (2008). Penile Growth After Puberty in Patients with a Constitutionally Small Penis. *Journal of Pediatric Urology, 4*, S63. doi: [10.1016/j.jpurol.2008.01.174](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jpurol.2008.01.174)

Laron, Z., Mimouni, F., & Pertzelan, A. (1983). Effect of human growth hormone therapy on penile and testicular size in boys with isolated growth hormone deficiency: first year of treatment. *Israel journal of medical sciences, 19*(4), 338-344. pmid: [6406387](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/6406387)

Comment: I can't answer this question, but I can say that if it were possible, somebody is willingly forgoing being a billionaire by not patenting their work.

Comment: The treatment must start **before puberty**, at age of 10, from what I've understood. This means the subject is **VERY** problematic on many aspects, so even if it "works", it's not a magic cure and is less glamorous than what it sounds like.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I found another study with subjects up to 24 years, and they managed to get results...https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3214853/

Comment: @CareyGregory Not really, it seems actually that science has forgotten about us with small penises, and nobody is willing to study about this. If I were a billionaire I'd be paying ppl to study this

Comment: @Freedo The market for penis enlargement is flooded with devices, surgeries, and supplements, so obviously nobody has forgotten. The market for such a product would be worth billions. I assure you that when you dangle billions in front of drug companies, they sit up and take notice.

Comment: @CareyGregory none of the stuff you said actually works

Comment: @Freedo Of course it doesn't. I didn't mean to imply it did.